# JS .filter() works when intereger is passed in, but not when variable is passed in

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use the .filter to pull an object out of an array of objects.

When I do this:

```
var homeCountry = this.props.searchedCountry.filter(country => country.id === 7);
```

I get a the filtered array, but when I do this:

```
var homeCountry = this.props.searchedCountry.filter(country => country.id === e.target.country.value);
```

where e.target.country.value === 7, I get an empty array.

Can anyone explain what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: `e.target.country.value`? Is that a typo or does your `e.target` node really have a `country` property that itself contains a `value` property?

Comment: @DavidThomas not a typo: <select defaultValue="" className="form-control user-auth" name="country">

Answer (score 1):

`e.target.value` is string value. you are doing strict comparison with datatype and value.

Updated Code

```
 var homeCountry = this.props.searchedCountry.filter(country => country.id === parseInt(e.target.country.value));
```

Comment: It works, but now I get the notification ' Line 12:  Expected '===' and instead saw '=='  eqeqeq'. Is there a way to make that go away? Can I convert e.target.country.value into an int?

Comment: `parseInt(e.target.country.value)`, or simply `(+e.target.country.value)`

Comment: wrap the `e.target.value` into `parseInt ` function and do `===` @peter176 Update my answer

Answer (score 0):

`e.target.value` will be a string, but they are several ways to handle this, is either you use `parseInt(e.target.value)` or `Number(e.target.value)` or `e.target.valueAsNumber`. And secondly `===` checks the value and also the data type of the operands you are comparing therefore ( `1 === "1"` ) will be evaluated as false but ( `1 === 1` ) will be evaluated as true, doing `==` will only compare the values, if you want to use `==` (non strict equal to ) it is not necessary that you should use the above suggested solution to handle the issue therefore ( `1 == 1` ) is true and ( `1 == "1"` ) is also true, but if you wish to use `===` (which is advisable) use the above suggested solution